# Mixing m and X in tabularx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, tabularx, ltxtable

I have a problem with tables containing m and X columns. I need one column which should be vertically centered and another one which should fill the available horizontal space. My problem is that the vertical alignment does not work as soon as I add a 'X' column. Is there a workaround to have both at the same time or did I do something conceptually wrong.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}    
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{0.75cm}|X|p{5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{NO} & \centering \textbf{Content} & \textbf{Signature} \\ \hline
        40 & \begin{itemize}
                \item some
                \item items
             \end{itemize}   & \\ \hline
        40 & \begin{itemize}
                \item some
                \item items
             \end{itemize}   & \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Since I think it might matter, I want to give a more complex example as well, as it is closer to my actual code. I have a really long table and therefore I am using `ltxtable` to allow page breaks and have the 'X' columns of `tabularx`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{activitytable.tex}
        \begin{longtable}{|M{0.75cm}|X|P{5cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{NO} & \centering \textbf{Content} & \textbf{Signature} \\ \hline
            40 & \begin{itemize}
                    \item some
                    \item items
                 \end{itemize}   & \\ \hline
            41 & \begin{itemize}
                    \item some
                    \item items
                 \end{itemize}   & \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{filecontents}

    \LTXtable{\textwidth}{activitytable}

\end{document}
```

In this simple case the result looks almost (not centered for the simple one) the same for both examples.
[image: wrong alignment]

I want it to look similar to this, but without filling in the width of the second column by myself.
[image: wrong width]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common misunderstanding about `m` it does *not* mean place the content in the middle of the vertical space for that cell. It means: place the reference point for the content in the middle of the content.

[image]

I added a line to your image showing the reference points of the cells in the second row, the reference point of column 1 is the middle of the 40 rather than the baseline, the reference point of the `X` column is its top as it is using `p` normally the reference point of `p` is the baseline of its first row, but as you have a displayed list the first item is a vertical space so the reference point is the top of the cell, so the reference points are placed on the red line, producing the effect that you see.

Possibly what you want to do is use `\tabularxcolumn` so that `X` is defined in terms of `m` not `p` then the red line would go through the vertical centre of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the problem now, though I do not know how I can fix it. Searching Google for `\tabularxformat` reveals nothing except this question. Can you please add more details to this part?

Comment: see the `tabularx` documentation, add `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` before the table.

Comment: I found it and it works as expected. Thanks.